# Pass a counter from a python thread to a wxpython gage?

Tags: python, wxpython, python-multithreading

I am trying to pass a counter from a python COM thread back into a wxpython tabpanel.  Anyone have a solution that would work.  Some of my code below:

This class is seperate from my wxPython code but is called out and data sent to this thread.

`class Log_COM_thread(Thread):
............
    def run(self):

        .............

        int_log_cnt = int_log_cnt + 1

        int_log.TabPanel.gauge.SetValue(int_log_cnt)

            if int_log_cnt == 64:

                int_log.TabPanel.Int_Log_Status.SetLabel('Extraction Complete')`

The seperate module, int_log, this counter value is being sent to is called out like this:

`class TabPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, range=72, size=(250, 25))

        .....and then more wxpython code.`

The error I run into is:

`Exception in thread Thread-8:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()

  File "F:\Documents and Settings\swhite\Desktop\OG GUI Working Jan 13\nbm.py", line 267, in run

    int_log.TabPanel.gauge.SetValue(int_log_cnt)

AttributeError: type object 'TabPanel' has no attribute 'gauge'`

How would I send my counter back to that gauge in wxpython from my external thread.  Any help in direction of how to do this would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call wx methods directly from a separate thread. You need to use one of wxPython thread-safe methods to communicate back to the main GUI thread. They are wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater and wx.PostEvent.

There is lots of information on threads and wx on the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks). I also wrote a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) on the subject that might help you.

Comment: The tutorial is very helpful.  Thank you!